# Where are my Ubuntu files (pictures, music) after reinstalling Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, files, data-recovery

I reinstalled Windows 7 on top of Ubuntu 11.10 and tried to get my Ubuntu desktop files (mostly pictures) using a Live CD (Ubuntu 11.10) but did not find them. I don't know where to search.

Then I reinstalled Ubuntu again from the Live CD and still did not find any of my pictures

Where is Ubuntu keeping the files? I can see the system from the Live CD but I don't know the path. How can I recover my files?

Comment: If you need to recover data you believe may be lost, it's imperative that you immediately shut down the newly installed system and not use it. You can run from a live CD *provided that swap is disabled*. See [the guidelines here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery). Once you've booted into an Ubuntu live CD system, please run `sudo fdisk -l` in a Terminal window (Ctrl+Alt+T) and **edit your question** to provide the full output (format it with the `<$>` tool so it appears correctly). That should show what partitions there are, and facilitate knowing if data recovery is needed.

Answer (score 1):

It's in `/home/username`, assuming that you didn't overwrite your Ubuntu partition.

Answer (score 0):

I think Ubuntu uses your home pictures folder `/home/{username}/Pictures`.